# BatchUpdateException while executing this query with twitter4j

Tags: java, mysql, twitter4j

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 're talking election 2016 with @ForbesOpinion's @Avik ' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatchInternal(StatementImpl.java:1048)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:958)
    at FirstTwitterApp.main(FirstTwitterApp.java:76)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 're talking election 2016 with @ForbesOpinion's @Avik ' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatchInternal(StatementImpl.java:1022)
    ... 2 more
```

The code:

```
Date your_date =  tweet.getCreatedAt() ;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd h:m:s");
String date = formatter.format(your_date);
String textStatus = tweet.getText();
System.out.println(textStatus);
String qry="insert into twitter_data(id,name,text_status,profile_picture,created_date)values(NULL,'"
        +tweet.getUser().getScreenName()+"','"
        +textStatus+"','"+tweet.getUser().getOriginalProfileImageURL()+"','"
        +date+"')";
connect.st.addBatch(qry);
connect.st.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Date your_date =  tweet.getCreatedAt() ;
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd h:m:s");
              String date = formatter.format(your_date);
              String textStatus = tweet.getText();
              System.out.println(textStatus);
             String qry="insert into twitter_data(id,name,text_status,profile_picture,created_date)values(NULL,'"+tweet.getUser().getScreenName()+"','"+textStatus+"','"+tweet.getUser().getOriginalProfileImageURL()+"','"+date+"')";
           connect.st.addBatch(qry); connect.st.executeBatch();

Comment: You might want to read what a SQL injection vulnerability is; and then use a `PreparedStatement` instead of building your SQL query as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your status text contains single quotes. Because you are not escaping the string before you build the query, this effectively closes the single quotes you are using to wrap the string.

**Never** build SQL queries by concatenating strings provided by the user. Search for "little Bobby Drop Tables" to find out why.

[Little Bobby Drop Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

**Always** use a `PreparedStatement` to build queries, as this automatically handles escaping for you.